# I need a condition for Whether image attachment existed or not

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

I have created image object like below

```
Image imgAttachement = new Image();
imgAttachement.setResource(Utils.getImageResource().getImAttachmentImage());
```

From Above code I need to know whether image exited or not I have tried like below

```
if(imgAttachement!=null){
   //some code here
}
```

But every time whether image existed or not its going inside of if condition....

Comment: Where do you attach this image? If you haven't a lot of images, you can put it in somewhere and then iterate it with your new image every time checking if it exists or not. If there aren't a lot of images,then this way fits.

Comment: check if (imgAttachement.exists() && imgAttachement.canRead()) 
its for file actually...but u can give it a try

Comment: exists and canread methods showing errors not applicable to imgAttachment

Comment: Please mention imports also. Object imgAttachement can't be null as per your code because you have created a new Image().

Answer (score 0):

Creates an image with a specified URL or ImageResource and add [LoadHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/LoadHandler.html) that will be fired once the image at the given URL has been retrieved by the browser.

Update a flag some where in the code and use it to test for its existence on the browser.

Sample code:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image;

Image imgAttachement = new Image("https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Krm.jpg?s=32&g=1");
imgAttachement.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Your stackoverflow profile icon has been loaded");
    }
});
```